# unit test web api actionresult index()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am new to unit testing web api in .net. I want to test an api controller, which returns different responses when the numbers and dates match.

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/json")]

public ActionResult<NumLookup> Index(string numA, string? numB, string? numDate)
        {
         NumLookup response = new NumLookup();
           
         List<NumLookupRecord> searchResult = new List<NumLookupRecord>();

         DateTime CheckNumDate;
         try
         {
              CheckNumDate = DateTime.ParseExact(NumDate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
         }
         catch
         {
               response.InfoCode = "Invalid";
               response.InvalidInfoCode = "Nill";
                
               return Ok(response);
          }

}
 return Ok(response);
```

I'm not sure if the setup is correct.

```
 public class DefaultControllerTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ReturnCorrectResponseCode()
        {
            DefaultController defaultController = new CreateDefaultController();
             var result = defaultController.Index("34534524", "467478678", "20251112");

            Assert.NotNull(result);
            Assert.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ContentResult), result);
            Assert.AreEqual("Invalid", result.Content);

        }
    }
```

Comment: So what's the issue here? What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: there is an error on this line and the test fails new CreateDefaultController();

Comment: You could check if you missed the parameters in constructor of your controller